# Setting onClickListener in one fragment and make it listens by another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments Fragment A and Fragment B. The FragmentA dynamically adds a view with `onclickListner`(Fragment B, that means fragment B listens ) to fragment B.Now when i click on added view (added by fragment A) in Fragment B, it doesn't work.

***Here is my code***.

**Fragment A**

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View last_user_layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_lastchatuser, null);

                    LinearLayout row_user = (LinearLayout) last_user_layout.findViewById(R.id.Llastchatuser);
                    row_user.setOnClickListener(new LastUsers());

                if (row_user.getParent() != null)
                    ((ViewGroup) row_user.getParent()).removeView(row_user);
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.last_user_container);
                linearLayout.addView(row_user);
```

//it successfully adds view in fragment B

**Fragment B (Last users)**

```
public class LastUsers extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public LastUsers() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_last_users, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.Llastchatuser){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
row_user.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);
row_user.setClickable(true);
```